# Program displaying "port opened/closed"

Tags: c, linux, port

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char command[100];
    char portrange[100];
    printf("Enter portrange (e.g.,20-30)");
    scanf("%s", portrange);
    int i=0, range1, range2;
    sscanf(portrange, "%d-%d", &range1, &range2);
    for(i=range1;i<=range2;i++)
    {
        sprintf(command, "netstat -aont | grep \"`hostname -i`:%d \" ", i);
        printf("command= %d \n", command); //printing the command for testing purpose only
        system(command);
       //here
       //here
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program filters out the lines from **netstat -aont | grep "`hostname -i`:%d "** where **%d** is successively replaced by the entered range of ports.

I want to add a if statement to display "port#%d is open" if port %d is opened if the command is successful or "port#%d is closed" if the command fails.
How can I achieve this inside the **for** loop?

N.B.: I used `%d` inside the `for` loop in port range checking. I know it is wrong but when I use `%s` it crashes with a core dump. Let’s ignore that for the moment.

Comment: For sure you need `printf("command=%s\n", command);` to refer to a string as the command; if it's faulting you have to look elsewhere.

Comment: You have any suggestion for other issue how can I do if check for port open then I print port x is open if close port # x is close etc ?

Answer (score 0):

The exit code of the pipeline command is the exit code of the last command in the pipeline. In your example, this is the exit code of `grep`. If `grep` succeeds, it exits with the value 0 otherwise it is different than 0.

[system()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) returns the status of the command line passed as parameter. So, you need to store the status in a variable:

```c
int status;
...
status = system(...);
```

You need to check the content of status with the [WIFEXIT() & WEXITSTATUS()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait). The latter macro will extract the exit code from the status:

```c
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
  int exit_code = WEXITSTATUS(status);
  printf("Exit code is %d\n", exit_code);
  // If exit_code is 0 ==> The grep succeeded
}
```